# Leonard Susskind's videos. Which order?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

As a mathematics student with almost no modern physics background (just an introduction to relativity when I was in secondary school) I find Leonard Susskind's lectures videos (freely available in Youtube) very interesting but I am wondering, in which order should I watch them? Which courses first? These are the ones I have found in Youtube:

- Modern Physics: Quantum Mechanics (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h1E3YJMKfA)
- Modern Physics: Special Relativity (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAurgxtOdxY)
- String Theory and M-Theory (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25haxRuZQUk)
- Einstein's General Theory of Relativity (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbmf0bB38h0)
- Quantum Entanglements (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Eeuqh9QfNI)
- Modern Physics: Classical Mechanics (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyX8kQ-JzHI)
- Cosmology (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32wIKaLkvc4)
- The Theoretical Minimum (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJfw6lDlTuA)

I would also appreciate if you could give links to more lectures from him (I mean full courses, there are plenty of talks available)

P.D. Sorry about the bad Tags, but i couldnt find something like 'student, learning, modern-physics'

Comment: Start with Classical Mechanics and make sure you understand everything. Then Quantum Entanglements must be studied after Quantum Mechanics. Furthermore, General Theory of Relativity must be studied after Special Relativity (but Relativity can be understood independently of Quantum Mechanics). Probably it is best to study Cosmology after General Theory of Relativity. All subjects are prerequisites before you can study String Theory and M-Theory.

Comment: I disagree with putting this question on hold. There is some logical order in the material of Susskind's lectures. Therefore an answer "almost entirely based on opinions" does not really apply in this case.

Comment: @Hunter thanks! Could you also comment about 'The Theoretical Minimum'?

Comment: More generally, soft questions asking for prerequisites or which order to study physics tend to fit poorly on Phys.SE for various reasons, e.g. _primarily opinion-based,_ or just obvious (E.g. why would one even ask whether one should study string theory before classical mechanics?). There also exist already many Phys.SE post about how to study physics. Another tip is to consult e.g. Wikipedia to see which subject is naturally a prerequisite to which subject.

Comment: @Qmechanic I didn't ask if I should study string theory before classical mechanics, rather I gave a list of subjects and I asked about the prerequisites between them which I think, are not primarily opinion-based. In fact Hunter's answer has been quite helpfull.

Comment: @Trollkemada You're welcome. I'm not sure about The Theoretical Minimum, but is certainly related to the Quantum Mechanics lectures - my guess would be that it should be studied before the Quantum Mechanics lectures, but I'm not sure.